# Jquery modal dialog disables its own controls

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a DIV to be shown as modal dialog in my ASP.Net MVC project. This DIV has a textbox to accept user input. However, when I open the dialog with modal option set to true, it disables this textbox as well along with parent form controls!

How do I enable the controls on the dialog when open as modal?

```
<div id="assumption-block" class="ic-assumption-block-pos">
    <input type="text" id="maxid" value="text" />
</div>
```

Script

```
$('#assumption-block').dialog({modal:true});
```

Comment: What plugin are you using to display the modal window?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: I use JQuery Dialog
$('#dialog-block').dialog({modal: true});

Comment: On the surface it sounds like a z-index issue. You can add a z-index property to the dialog params object `{ z-index: 1000 }` to force it to use a base z-index of your choice.

Comment: @Anil Soman does this behaviour only occur when you set `modal:true`?

Comment: @mattematico Yes only when modal is true.

Comment: @Anil Soman, try my poor solution, it might fix your problem.?

Comment: @AnilSoman: Something local is interfering with your controls. When adding your code into a fiddle it works as expected. You need to look at your rendered HTML using the debug tool in your browser to check if there is any disabled attributes on your controls. Until then your issue is very localized and any solution would be purely based on speculation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct solution, but it might work for this problem, try add the second code line to your script. It might work, but your problem seems strange.

```
$('#assumption-block').dialog({ modal: true });
$('#assumption-block input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: not working.. I will check using firebug what is being rendered

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this issue myself. If you had the same issue I had I believe the correct fix is to change the z-index such that `$(".ui-dialog")` has a greater z-index than `$(".ui-widget-overlay")` in css land.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen to me. It was caused by having a link to version 1.9.2 of the smoothness css, and 1.11.4 of the jquery ui js. I believe it has to do with z index changes made in the css by jquery

Comment: Thanks a billion this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

so you want to this way [see this link](http://jsfiddle.net/zK4gc/)

you can set open method to remove attr disabled;

```
$('#assumption-block').dialog({ 
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) { 
        $('#assumption-block input').removeAttr('disabled');  
    }
});​
```